# how to intercept messages in botbuilder sdk v4 using middleware?

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, azure-cognitive-services

I have a Bot running on botbuilder V3 where I am using a middleware explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-intercept-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#example) to intercept the messages.

```
bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {
        myMiddleware.logIncomingMessage(session, next);
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        myMiddleware.logOutgoingMessage(event, next);
    }
})
```

We are planning to migrate on sdk v4 so looking for similar capabilities in sdk v4. Are there any ?

I didn't find example on this [page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#handling-state-in-middleware)

Answer (score 2):

The `BotAdapter` base class exposes the `use` method to register middleware. So in your startup logic you'll create a specific implementation of a `BotAdapter`, typically `BotFrameworkAdapter`, and then add the middleware to it. Like so:

```js
const botAdapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter( { /* credential stuff here*/ });

// Simple handler based
botAdapter.use(async (turnContext, next) => {
    // pre logic

    await next();

    // post logic
});

// Or class based
botAdapter.use(new MyMiddleware());
```

Comment: Thanks. One more question how do we differentiate activities from Bot to user & user to bot. Ex:- in v3 we had 2 event handlers botbuilder & send.

Comment: Sure, happy to help! Would you mind opening a new question regarding differentiating? It's considered bad form to answer follow up questions in the comments as it makes it harder for people to find when searching for answers. When you do I'll jump in and give you an answer AQAP. 

Comment: @vijay Is turnContext in v4 similar to 'session' in v3?