# How to store user conversation in bot framework v4 using Node Mysql Api

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, botframework, bots

Bot Framework latest version ,

I want to store all user conversation on node mysql backend

How to achieve this task ?

Comment: do you want to update mysql with conversations in real time or in batch?

Comment: Update real-time conversation on MySQL database using node api

Answer (score 0):

Considering you need real-time updates, there are 2 solutions:

**Through CosmosDB**

This [article](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/21/saving-state-azure-nodejs/) explains how to setup conversation storage in CosmosDB.

```
var docDbClient = new azure.DocumentDbClient(documentDbOptions);
var tableStorage = new azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, docDbClient);
```

Once you have data stored there, you can either do a batch job which exports to MySQL on a cron basis, or use the [change feed](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-change-feed-dotnet-retail-sample). So for every entry in CosmosDB, you will do an INSERT in your MySQL, using an Azure Function.

**Through Middleware**

In you messaging endpoint app, intercept all incoming and outgoing messages using middleware. More details in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-intercept-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

```
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {
        myMiddleware.saveIncomingMessage(session, next);
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        myMiddleware.saveOutgoingMessage(event, next);
    }
})
```

And then do an INSERT for every message:

```
module.exports = {
    saveIncomingMessage: function (session, next) {
        // INSERT session.message.text
        next();
    },
    saveOutgoingMessage: function (event, next) {
        // INSERT event.text;
        next();
    }
}
```

---

I prefer through middleware as it has less moving parts.

Comment: except cosmos db, having any solution  for storing real time updates on mysql db

Comment: @SathisSakthivel , yes, check the second option - Through Middleware

Comment: It's OK, but mentioned code Bot framework 3.0 , i am using 4.0, that's not suitable

Comment: it is mostly the same thing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225716/how-to-intercept-messages-in-botbuilder-sdk-v4-using-middleware

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to incorporate the MySQL npm pacakge, located [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), into your project. Once you have the connection configured and established, it's just a matter of passing in the data you want from the activity.

You would likely want to build this a middleware layer so each activity is passed thru. Then, in the middleware, you would parse the activity and save it to your MySQL database. You can read more about middleware in the BotFramework [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). There are a couple links at the end of the doc that point to middleware samples, for reference.

The code, in its most basic form, would look something like this:

```js
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Do you have this solution for Python? Because I'm using Bot Framework in Python and I'm trying to save my chats in MySQL in real time. So can you please help me out?